# Spring Boot & Thymeleaf - remove strict HTML error checking

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot for an MVC application, and my view technology is Thymeleaf. One of the things I need to do is copy the HTML of an existing website (not my doing...) and render it using Thymeleaf. However, some of the website's source HTML contain unclosed HTML tags (such as `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<input>`), or HTML tags with elements not surrounded by quotes, for example:

```html
<div id=1></div>
```

instead of

```html
<div id="1"></div>
```

Of course in the browser this works... But Thymeleaf will not allow this and doesn't serve the page. Is there any way to allow more lenient rules for this? I've searched Thymeleaf's documentation and Spring Boot reference and have found no answer.

Just for clarification - I've not even configured my own beans for Thyemeleaf, just added it to the classpath via maven as one of the spring-boot-starters. So right now these are default settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @mussdroid said, everything needs to be in valid XML.  Here is part of Thymeleaf's documentation explaining the background for this: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/fromhtmltohtmlviahtml.html

Also, if this is a problem, I believe you can turn on legacy-mode to allow non-XML templates, though I would prefer using valid XML if possible:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#what-kind-of-templates-can-thymeleaf-process

I don't know myself how to change the mode, but I'm sure DuckDuckGo does or someone on this site.

Comment: In the link you've provided, Legacy HTML is probably what I'm looking for. But when I choose that option, then my Angularjs code stops working... Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, according to that second link, Thymeleaf modifies your HTML to make it valid XML before it processes it and outputs it. Not sure but I could definitely imagine that screwing up Angular.  You might be able to structure your stuff in a way to make it work, but I would probably just make everything valid XML, if it's not too much work.

Comment: There is actually no error - angular expressions, binding etc. are not working.
What I did is to use an online tool to convert html to xhtml. I will probably have to ditch Thymeleaf because of these kinds of things.
Nevertheless, you did answer my question, so I've selected your answer:).

Comment: k, thanks.  good luck! Are all of them not working, or just some of them?

Comment: All of them, apparently. It's as if I didn't include an ng-app element in the DOM.

Comment: What if you make just the angular stuff valid xml? like <div ng-app="ng-app"></div> or <div ng-app="true"></div> or something.

Answer (score 13):

I know i am giving answer after long time but still if it can help to anyone it's good to share.

I resolved the problem after setting up one property 
 "spring,thymeleaf.mode" to "LEGACYHTML5".

```
 spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

And in the pom.xml, add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
  <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.21</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to disable caching of thymeleaf then thymeleaf caching

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot 1.5.3 [supports](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3) Thymeleaf 3. Thymeleaf 3 has [full html5 markup support.](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html#full-html5-markup-support)

Add following lines to your `pom.xml` to override Thymeleaf version in Spring boot and you'll be able to use unclosed tags.

```
<properties>
   <thymeleaf.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
   <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    ...
</properties>
```

Comment: The best answer in my opinion. Careful that the code pasted in the answer should be added inside <properties>.

Answer (score 3):

Everything should be xthml format

For example ;

HTML LINK

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

THYMELEAF  LINK SHOULD BE ending with "/> "

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

HTML META

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

THYMELEAF META SHOULD BE ending with "/>"

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Samples

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" disabled /> wrong 

<input type="text" name="lastname" disabled="disabled" /> correct
```

otherwise pages will not be displayed because of xhmtl rules applied.

Please have a look at the link , avoid this kind of mistakes 
[HTML and XHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp)

On the other hand when the page is return to browser you will see xhtml rules  converts to html format again. But the actually page it run on a server before sending client thymeleaf xhtml rules are applied.